# Store User Defined Object Class

Tags: java, android, object, sharedpreferences, store

In my android project I defined a simple class conists of some variables and get and set methods as follows:

```
public   class Chest 
private  int id;
private  String phoneNumber;
private  String deliverer;
private  String postCode;
private  String town;
private  String description;

public  int getId(){
    return id;
}
public  void setId(int id){
    this.id=id;
}


public  String getPhoneNumber(){
    return phoneNumber;
}
public  void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
    this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
}


public  String getDeliverer(){
    return deliverer;
}
public  void setDeliverer(String deliverer){
    this.deliverer=deliverer;
}


public  String getPostCode(){
    return postCode;
}
public  void setPostCode(String postCode){
    this.postCode=postCode;
}


public  String getTown(){
    return town;
}
public  void setTown(String town){
    this.town=town;
}


public  String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
public  void setDescription(String description){
    this.description=description;
}
```

So I want to make user define instances of this class using set methods  and give it a unique name so he could refer to it later and acquire it's values. The only way i know of storing data is sharedpreference which only store primitive values. So is there any way I could do this job fast with sharedpreference or I have to learn database for doing this job and how is it possible?

Comment: serialize the class and store as file .

Answer (score 0):

to achieve that you need to store the data in database and for that use
 realm database as it is easy to integrate and is much faster than sqlite database
https://realm.io/